# The "table" form alignment with the inputs inside labels

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to avoid using `id` for every form element. But I also want to keep the table layout.

`<label>` works without the `id` when you put the input inside the label:

```
<label>Something: <input type="text" ... /> </label>
```

But now it's sudenly pretty hard to make inputs or the label contents float to sides to make it look like a table. I've been trying the `margin: auto` on inputs. [Without any success.](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/bhuy1t1x/)

What do you sugest?

Comment: You could put `Something:` inside a HTML element and make that float?

Comment: Would that remain semantically correct?

Comment: As far as I know, label is supposed to *mean*, that the text it contains describes associated text field. And I thought such meanings are called semantic.

Comment: In HTML context, “semantics” is idle talk about words; the real thing here is *functional* association between labels and controls (e.g., if you click on a label, the control gets focused). This is best achieved using `label` elements with `for` attributes referring to controls via their `id` attributes, so why would you want to avoid it? Trying to do so is more work than adding those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table and create a class with a specific width for those columns that contain the labels.

```
form.myform table tr td.label {
    width:100px;
}
```

[Check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/bhuy1t1x/6/)

Comment: The input's are not inside the labels buddy :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using correct markup with ID, if you don't want to write ID for each element, create a simple jQuery or JS function which assigns `for` attribute for label and equivalent `id` for input field.

Comment: There's nothing incorrect with putting `input`s in the `label`s as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest, that you shouldn't put input element inside label element. Label has a attribute called "for" so you should do:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="myInput"></label> <input id="myInput"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you don't want to use tables for alignment, you could also use sections with `div`s to build a table-like layout.

Comment: I stated that I don't want to use `id`. Label's `for` attribute stands for target's `id`, not `name`. Otherwise, it would be ambigious.